# Loading the XML in webpart

Tags: sharepoint

How do I upload the XML file in the SharePoint library?

Answer (score 0):

Try this post for sample code: [File Upload web part](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointcustomization/thread/18e6a7fa-9122-48b5-996b-c80397f536e8)